# syntax error in configure

Tags: software-installation

I use ubuntu 16.04 and want to compile Tcl7.5 and Tk4.1 . But when I want to configure by the command that mentioned in the Tcl's homepage after some configurations I face with this error:
checking system version (for dynamic loading)... ./configure: 1: ./configure: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string.
could anyone helpes me?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the exact cause of the error - it's probably something deep in the bowels of [how autoconf attempts to deal with](http://invisible-island.net/autoconf/portability-echo.html) the [non-portability of the `echo` command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/65304). However you can try a couple of workarounds as follows:

1. The existing `configure` script appears to work if run explicitly using `bash` i.e. `bash configure` in place of `./configure`

[Perhaps when Tcl7.5 was packaged, it was reasonable to assume that `/bin/sh` was `bash` - Ubuntu now has [`dash` as `/bin/sh`](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh)]

2. You can run `autoreconf -f` in the same directory to create a new `configure` script that should be compatible with the current `autoconf`

Either way, I would be surprised if you didn't run into further issues building such (20-year-) old software - good luck.